# How can I use office navigation bar like backstageview in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, navigation, devexpress

I want to use Office navigation bar like backstage view control. For example, I get information like customers name, birthday, and files but I can separate with backstage view can I do same with office navigation bar?

I found this link:

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/build-outlook-app.xml

but it did not help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can implement such sort of functionality, but I am not sure that it will be exactly same as the WPF controls - [Backstage View](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10507). You should check the documentation of Navigation bar's [Navigation Frame](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114554) functionality and [Office Navigation Bar](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument114558).

> As I discovered that Office Navigation Bar control is its ability to
>   integrate with a NavBarControl. In one of the integration scenarios it
>   may be similar to desired functionality..
>
> An external NavBarControl's groups can be displayed as an Office
>   Navigation Bar's items.

[image]

Hope this give you an idea that how to implement the desired navigation as you want.