# Treelist in DevExpress (how to use Focus Change event)

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I am new using Dev Express I want to use a (devexpress) TreeList as a menu in my application (vbnet). I don't know how to make a node clickable to go to a form.

[image]

Please find below the treelist that I inplement
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

First go through the documentation: [Tree List](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2434) to know that how this control works and then implement data in the tree list then do navigation stuff in below manner:

To respond to change in node selection, you can handle the [TreeList.SelectionChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_SelectionChangedtopic.aspx) event. To use it as Menu then you must set [TreeListOptionsSelection.MultiSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeListOptionsSelection_MultiSelecttopic.aspx) property to **false**. The SelectionChanged event fires each time a node is selected or deselected in such a case.

Then you can obtain the focused node using the [TreeList.FocusedNode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FocusedNodetopic) property. Then, use its [TreeListNode.GetValue](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodesTreeListNode_GetValuetopic) method to obtain a value of a specific column.

example code in c#:

```
private void treeList1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Write your code to open a form dialog after getting information 
   // using the required condition that you have

       Form form = GetNavigationFormForNode(treeList1.GetDisplayText(columnDep));
       if(form != null)
       {
          form.ShowDialog();
       }

}
```

***In case of fouused Node concern:***
I suggest you go through documentation section "[Respond to Focus Movement](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument212)" of TreeList. Then you can respond to moving focus between nodes by handling the [TreeList.FocusedNodeChanged](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FocusedNodeChangedtopic.aspx) event.

The event handler receives an argument of type [FocusedNodeChangedEventArgs](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraTreeListFocusedNodeChangedEventArgstopic.aspx) containing data related to this event. There you can get the current Tree List node from the [Node](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListNodeEventArgs_Nodetopic.aspx) property.

**Reference:**
[How can I get data record for focused row in TreeList?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q457375)
[How to get tree list selected node text?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q362000)

For using navigation bar for single form implementation then check it:
[How can I use office navigation bar like backstageview in winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783006/how-can-i-use-office-navigation-bar-like-backstageview-in-winforms/33802329#33802329)